# QLayout.replace not replacing

Tags: pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

I have the following code to **replace** a widget (`self.lbl`) each time I click on a button (`self.btn`):

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import Slot
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, \
        QPushButton


class Workshop(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.n = 0
        self.btn = QPushButton('Push me')
        self.lbl = QLabel(str(self.n))

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.sub_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.sub_layout.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.sub_layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.sub_layout)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.change_label)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.show()

    @Slot()
    def change_label(self):
        new_label = QLabel(str(self.n + 1))
        self.main_layout.replaceWidget(self.lbl, new_label)
        self.n += 1
        self.lbl = new_label


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()

    w = Workshop()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Right after its initialization, the object `w` looks like this:
[image]

When I click on the "Push me" button (`self.btn`), the number is incremented as wanted, but the initial "0" remains in the background:

[image]

But the other numbers do not however remain in the background ; only "0" does. Fore example, here is "22" (result after I clicked 22 times on "Push me"):

[image]

**Note:** *I **know** that I could achieve the resultant I want with the `setText` method, but this code is just a snippet that I will adapt for a class in which I will not have a method like `setText`.*

Thank you!

Comment: Add the line `self.lbl.hide()` before the line `self.main_layout.replaceWidget(self.lbl, new_label)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you replace the widget in the layout, the previous one still remains there.
From [`replaceWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#replaceWidget):

> The parent of widget from is left unchanged.

The problem is that when a widget is removed from a layout, it still keeps its parent (in your case, the `Workshop` instance), so you can still view it. This is more clear if you set the alignment to `AlignCenter` for each new QLabel you create: you'll see that if you add a new label and resize the window, the previous one will keep its previous position:

```
class Workshop(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.lbl = QLabel(str(self.n), alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        # ...

    def change_label(self):
        new_label = QLabel(str(self.n + 1), alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        # ...
```

You have two possibilities, which are actually very similar:

- set the parent of the "removed" widget to `None`: the garbage collector will remove the widget as soon as you overwrite `self.lbl`:

```
    self.lbl.setParent(None)
```

- remove the widget by calling [`deleteLater()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) which is what happens when reparenting a widget to None and, if it has no other persisting references, gets garbage collected:

```
    self.lbl.deleteLater()
```

For your pourposes, I'd suggest you to go with `deleteLater()`, as calling `setParent()` (which is a reimplementation of QObject's setParent) actually does lots of other things (most importantly, checks the focus chain and resets the widget's window flags), and since the widget is going to be deleted anyway, all those things are actually unnecessary, and QObject's implementation of `setParent(None)` would be called anyway.

The graphic "glitch" you are facing might depend on the underlying low-level painting function, which has some (known) unexpected behaviors on MacOS in certain cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot @musicamante! Your answer is both helpful code-wise and insightful. Should I put `self.lbl.deleteLater()` before or after `self.main_layout.replaceWidget(self.lbl, new_label)`?

Comment: And by the way, any idea why the bug was only for the 0 but not the other numbers?

Comment: The order is not that important (since `deleteLater`, as the name suggests, deletes the object _later_), but I suggest you to put it *after* replacing the widget in the layout, just for logic and coherency matters. As said, the glitch might depend on those bugs under MacOS, I don't know anything more.